# Missing publisher name in windows Dialog during installation

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64, install4j

I have created installer executable using Install4j IDE. When I am taking the executable and running the executable on some other system. I am getting a warning dialog. On which Publisher name is missing.

Please refer the attached image.

[image]

I have already set the publisher name in application info tab under general setting in install4j IDE.

How can I get publisher name on  windows dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sign your installer, then the name in your code signing certificate will be displayed in the UAC prompt. The publisher text field in install4j is only used for the uninstall information in the windows control panel.